# how to login in drupal from php external site

Tags: php, drupal, oauth

I'm new in drupal I want to login to my drupal site from a php site, I'm using the service and oauth module. Already tried login with session authentication and returns the ssesion id and name what I don't know is how to redirect to the drupal site logged. I also try the 3 legged authentication using my own consummer but if the user is not logged in drupal it ask to login and then do the token authentication so I'm stuck in how to login the user before the 3 legged authentication. Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install [services](http://www.drupal.org/project/services) module in Drupal. Configure the same to expose the login service. Once enabled you can call it in your php application. Refer this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1407736) for example.

Comment: I already did this. I have a session_id and session_name also a token and the user info. what I need to do now is to redirect the user from my php site to the drupal site already logged. Thanks